# Spring Boot не открывается сайт

Tags: java, spring-boot

В Idea при запуске приложения не открывает сайт в браузере хотя до этого всё открывалось. В коде программы нет ошибок, доходит до

```
2023-10-01T20:38:47.337+03:00  INFO 13396 --- [main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer: Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path

2023-10-01T20:38:47.346+03:00  INFO 13396 --- [main] org.sp_boot.SpBootApplication: Started SpBootApplication in 3.728 seconds (process running for 6.378)
```

Аавтоматического перехода в браузер нет.
Если вводить адрес сайта вручную, то страница открывается. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Нужен код, так то у тебя он запустился и всё ок. Не информативно

Comment: Дмитрий, здравствуйте. Какой именно код?Код из консоли при запуске  Spring boot?Вручную я открываю  страницу localhost8080/ с надписью Привет

Comment: Код программы, где у вас вызывается браузер с ссылкой страницы, которой должна открыться.
Так Ваш вопрос не информативен.
Вот томкат запустился и ничего не происходит, а как нужно понять, что происходит под капотом вашего проекта?